# Move to SD Card?

Tags: android, html, webview, sd-card

I have an app "Gurbani Ujagar" which views about 3000 HTMl pages using WebView. I have received many emails about adding an move to SD Card option. I have no idea what that means, how that makes a difference, and how I can add this option?

Comment: Presumably your users want you to save the translations on the SD card, so that they can save a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually incredibly easy to do!  First, make sure your target API level is 8 or higher.  If it is, you can simply include this code in your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
... >
```

For more information, check out [this android developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html).

Comment: But what difference does it make? How would it benefit them?

Comment: Good question!  Many Android devices have a very limited amount of data that they can store.  It looks like Gurbani Ujagar takes up over 15MB of data on the device- a huge amount for devices that might have only 250MB or 300MB (common in devices more than 2 years old).  Allowing them to install to SD will make the app take up much less (usually less than 1MB) and will instead store that data on an external card (which is much cheaper and easier to add more)

Comment: Wonderful explanation! Thanks a lot for your help. :)